# ValueError and ambiguous truth value when using if statement in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I get this error when I run my if statement in Pandas:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My code:

```
FTorPT = {
'Full-time': 30,
'Part-time': 18,
}

df['Remainder'] = (df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT) - df['Hours'])

df['Top-up'] = df['Hours'].apply(lambda x: df['Remainder'] + df['Hours'] if x < df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT) else df['Hours'])
```

So what I'm trying to figure out how many hours we need to top-up if they're a Full-Time or Part-Time worker. Their minimum is 30 and 18.

The if statement I'm trying to execute is supposed to add the `Remainder` hours (the minimum hours - hours worked) and add it to the existing `Hours` that they actually worked to reach the minimum. Otherwise, if they exceeded the hours for the week, then just return Hours worked.

Is there another way I can do this where I can just replace their hours worked with either 18 or 30 depending on their `Work Status` if the hours is < the numbers in the `FTorPT` dict.

**Sample Data**

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'Work Status': ['Part-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Part-time'],
      'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
      'Hours': [11.23, 18.91, 35, 18],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

FTorPT = {
    'Full-time': 30,
    'Part-time': 18,
}

df['Remainder'] = (df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT) - df['Hours'])

df['Top-up'] = df['Hours'].apply(lambda x: df['Remainder'] + df['Hours'] if x < df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT) else df['Hours'])

per_courier = df.groupby(["ID"]).agg(sum)
print(per_courier)
```

**Expectations**

1. ID 1 would return a `Remainder` of 6.77 hours and the `Hours`
   returned should be 18
2. ID 2 would return a `Remainder` of 11.09 hours
   and the `Hours` returned should be
3. ID 3 would return no `Remainder`
   and the `Hours` returned should be 35 as they exceeded their minimum
4. ID 4 would return no `Remainder` and the `Hours` returned should be 18 as they met their minimum

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: thanks to @Paul H for his comment. Adding his solution first.
Note that `.apply()` is generally only used when functions can't be vectorized.
Instead of using `.apply()` you can -- and most likely should -- utilize `np.where()`:

```
import numpy as np 

df["top-up"] = np.where(df["Hours"] < df["Work Status Hours"], 
                        df["Remainder"] + df["Hours"], 
                        df["Hours"])
```

---

Original answer:
I suggest not trying to do the map inside the lambda; that operation would execute way too many times. And then you need `axis=1` to indicate that `.apply()` must operate on columns instead of rows which is `axis=0`, and is the default, reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html Also, when you're using lambda the scope doesn't include `df` that I know of so be sure to use the lambda variable(s) only. Example solution:

```
df['Work Status Hours'] = df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT)
df['Top-up'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['Remainder'] + x['Hours']) 
                        if x['Hours'] < x['Work Status Hours'] 
                        else x['Hours'], axis=1)
```

Result -- lmk if that's the result you expected:

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]: 
  Work Status  ID  Hours  Remainder  Work Status Hours  Top-up
0   Part-time   1  11.23       6.77                 18    18.0
1   Full-time   2  18.91      11.09                 30    30.0
2   Full-time   3  35.00      -5.00                 30    35.0
3   Part-time   4  18.00       0.00                 18    18.0
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I'm glad I wasn't too far off the mark with my own answer :D

Comment: No, not really! Because it was close at first I couldn't figure out what was going wrong, haha.

Comment: `numpy.where` would vectorize this for you: `df["top-up"] = numpy.where(df["Hours] < df["Work Status Hours"], df["Remainder"] + df["Hours"], df["Hours"])`.

Comment: (the goal of vectorization being a speedup for non-trivally sized dataframes)

Comment: @PaulH: thanks, that's the ideal way. Edited answer to include your solution with attribution.

Comment: Thanks to both for the answer! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Hey I've run into some issues with the code as the hours provided aren't weekly hours but rather daily. I forgot about this when I created the small sample code. Could you help me with this as I've tried using `.groupby` to get the weekly hours but an Index Error pops up. Would you be able to help me with this question at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382565/indexerror-when-i-added-another-groupby-with-pandas

Comment: @cchev: I suggest to create a new question. It'll get more eyes on it. Honestly not using pandas a whole lot on a regular basis, so might be more difficult for me to answer.