# IndexError when I added another .groupby() with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I get an IndexError when I added this line into my code

```
df['Weekly Hours'] = df.groupby(['Full Name'])['Hours'].agg(sum)
```

I'm trying to figure out how many hours each person has worked with the daily hours I'm provided with.

I have to use this code as I'm trying to find out how many hours I need to add to each person, to make sure they're paid their minimum contract hours:

```
df['Total hours'] = np.where(df['Weekly Hours'] < df['Contract Hours'], df['Top-up Hours'] + df['Weekly Hours'], df['Weekly Hours'])
```

Initially the code worked fine without the extra `.groupby` line that I had to add in after to get `Weekly Hours`

I have 2 other `.groupbys` to finish off the code as this will be returned into an .xlsx format with 2 sheets called `Per Day` and `Employees`:

```
Per_Day = df.groupby(['Start Date', 'Full Name', 'Work Status']).agg({'Hours': 'sum'})
Employees = df.groupby(['Full Name', 'Top-up Hours']).agg({'Weekly Hours': 'sum', 'Start Date':'nunique'})
```

The issue seems to impact the `Employees` line.

Any ideas on what I've done or how to fix this? I'm open to other ideas on how I can get weekly hours per employee without using `.groupby` since that seems to be the issue.

Thank you.

**Sample Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'Work Status': ['Part-time', 'Part-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Part-time', 'Part-time'],
      'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
      'Hours': [4.67, 5.07, 3.50, 4, 3.10, 6.90, 2.92, 5.50, 9, 9],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

FTorPT = {
    'Full-time': 30,
    'Part-time': 18,
}
df['Weekly Hours'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Hours'].agg(sum)
df['Contract Hours'] = df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT)
df['Top-up Hours'] = (df['Contract Hours'] - df['Weekly Hours'])

df['Total hours'] = np.where(df['Weekly Hours'] < df['Contract Hours'], df['Top-up Hours'] + df['Weekly Hours'], df['Weekly Hours'])

Per_Day = df.groupby(['Date', 'ID', 'Work Status']).agg({'Hours': 'sum'})
Employees = df.groupby(['ID', 'Top-up Hours']).agg({'Weekly Hours': 'sum', 'Date':'nunique'})

df.to_excel(r'filepath', header=True)

book = load_workbook(r'filepath')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'filepath', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

Per_Day.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Per Day')
Employees.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Employees')
writer.close()
```

Comment: The `Weekly Hours` column doesn't exist in your sample data...

Comment: Because you don't have that column in your dataframe (in the sample data at least)

Comment: Now `'Full Name'` does not exist. Maybe `ID`?

Comment: Sorry yes Full name is ID. Just thought it would be easier to have it as ID numbers @Corralien

Comment: So in your example `df['Weekly Hours'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['Hours'].agg(sum)` works well

Comment: Your example data is not reproducible the dict should be called data and the different columns (values) are of diverging length e.g. `{k: len(v) for k,v in data.items()}` = {'Work Status': 10, 'ID': 8, 'Hours': 10} and the `date` column is missing. Your error is not reproducible