# KeyError in Pandas when the column name is definitely there

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to work out how many hours each ID is contracted to based on their work status i.e. Part-Time or Full-Time.

To do this, I need to know their weekly total hours when I'm given their daily totals. So what I've done is

```
FTorPT = {
'Full-time': 30,
'Part-time': 18,
}
df['Hours'] = df['Total shift hours']

df['Contract Hours'] = df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT)
```

I needed a sum of total hours PER ID so I thought I could aggregate the data first and get weekly hours per ID. Without this, line, it would subtract the daily hours by the `Contract Hours` which would be wrong.

```
W = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours']).agg({'Hours':'sum'})
```

*Update to this section*
Even with @Quang Hoang's suggestion to change it to:

```
W = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours'], as_index=False)['Hours'].sum()
```

It still returns the daily hours rather than an accumulation of the hours over the week.

To know how many hours I need to add to meet their minimum, I've done this:

```
W['Top-up Hours'] = (W['Contract Hours']-W['Hours'])
```

The issue occurs in this line as I get `Key Error: 'Contract Hours'` when the column clearly exists.

Where have I gone wrong in the code?

***Also Tried:***

Instead of a new dataframe and replacing it with `W`, I've also tried obtaining weekly hours by doing this

```
df['Weekly Hours'] = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours']).agg({'Hours':'sum'})
```

but it returns a `Index Error` which I've asked a question for here but I couldn't figure it out - [IndexError when I added another .groupby() with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382565/indexerror-when-i-added-another-groupby-with-pandas?noredirect=1#comment124414749_70382565).

**Sample Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'Work Status': ['Part-time', 'Part-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Part-time', 'Part-time'],
      'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
      'Hours': [4.67, 5.07, 3.50, 4, 3.10, 6.90, 2.92, 5.50, 9, 9],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

FTorPT = {
    'Full-time': 30,
    'Part-time': 18,
}
df['Contract Hours'] = df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT)

W = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours']).agg({'Hours':'sum'})
W['Top-up Hours'] = (W['Contract Hours'] - W['Hours'])

W['Total hours'] = np.where(W['Hours'] < W['Contract Hours'], W['Top-up Hours'] + W['Hours'], W['Hours'])

Per_Day = W.groupby(['Date', 'ID', 'Work Status']).agg({'Hours': 'sum'})
Employees = W.groupby(['ID', 'Top-up Hours']).agg({'Hours': 'sum', 'Date':'nunique'})

df.to_excel(r'filepath', header=True)

book = load_workbook(r'filepath')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'filepath', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

Per_Day.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Per Day')
Employees.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Employees')
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `W = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours']).agg({'Hours':'sum'})`, `Contract Hours` is the second level index, not a column, so the subsequent
`W['Top-up Hours'] = (W['Contract Hours'] - W['Hours'])` fails on `W['Contract Hours']`. You want

```
W = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours']).agg({'Hours':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Or, better, without using `agg`:

```
W = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours'], as_index=False)['Hours'].sum()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, it seems to have worked for the `Contract Hours` part but I have another line where it looks for date that I did not include in the question because I didn't think it was relevant. To fix this, do you have a link to any documentation to explain this indexing issue? I'd like to look into it more to get a better understanding :)

Comment: Filtering it by `groupby` also doesn't seem to work either. It still returns the daily total rather than a weekly total. So therefore, it'll subtract the daily hours - `contract hours` giving me the wrong total hours :/ Any ideas?