# ValueError with .groupby - Wrong number of items passed

Tags: python, pandas

I get this error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 15, placement implies 1
```

When I try to run this line

```
df['Weekly Hours'] = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False)['Hours'].agg(sum)
```

I'm trying to figure out the total weekly hours each person has worked with the daily hours I'm provided with. To do this I've created a dictionary to refer to:

```
FTorPT = {
'Full-time': 30,
'Part-time': 18,
}
df['Contract Hours'] = df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT)
```

My current issue is that without using `groupby` to get `Weekly Hours`, it'll subtract the minimum `Contract Hours` with the daily hours and return the wrong sum.

For example, if a person has worked 5.60 hours on 1 days and they're a Full-Time Employee, it'll do `30 - 5.60` rather than take their weekly total hours.

To understand how many hours I need to add based on their contracted minimum hours:

```
df['Top-up Hours'] = (df['Contract Hours']-df['Weekly Hours'])

df['Total hours'] = np.where(df['Weekly Hours'] < df['Contract Hours'], df['Contract Hours'], df['Weekly Hours'])
```

The `np.where` also won't work as it takes `Weekly Hours` to be the daily hours so the condition will always be true and replace the hours with their `Contract Hours` for each day.

I've also tried changing the dataframe and filtering it through that
`W = df.groupby(['ID', 'Contract Hours'], as_index=False)['Hours'].sum()` but it doesn't work.

I had to add `as_index=False` otherwise I'd get a `KeyError: 'Contract Hours'` error.
Initially I'd get an IndexError before I added the `as_index=False` shown in this question - [IndexError when I added another .groupby() with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382565/indexerror-when-i-added-another-groupby-with-pandas?noredirect=1#comment124414749_70382565).

I apologise for repeating the question so many times with different errors. But every time I make amends to the code it comes up with a different error and I've tried different ways around it.

**Sample Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = {'Work Status': ['Part-time', 'Part-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Full-time', 'Part-time'],
      'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
      'Hours': [4.67, 5.07, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6.90, 2.92, 5.50],
      }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

FTorPT = {
    'Full-time': 30,
    'Part-time': 18,
}
df['Contract Hours'] = df['Work Status'].map(FTorPT)

df['Weekly Hours'] = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index=False)['Hours'].agg(sum)
df['Top-up Hours'] = (df['Contract Hours'] - df['Hours'])

df['Total hours'] = np.where(df['Weekly Hours'] < df['Contract Hours'], df['Contract Hours'], df['Hours'])

Per_Day = df.groupby(['Date', 'ID', 'Work Status']).agg({'Hours': 'sum'})
Employees = df.groupby(['ID', 'Top-up Hours']).agg({'Weekly Hours': 'sum', 'Date':'nunique'})

df.to_excel(r'filepath', header=True)

book = load_workbook(r'filepath')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'filepath', engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

Per_Day.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Per Day')
Employees.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Employees')
writer.close()
```

Expectations

1. ID 1 would return 8.26 as `Top-up Hours` and the `Weekly Hours` returned should be 18 as they're Part-Time
2. ID 2 would return -2 as `Top-up Hours` and the `Weekly Hours` returned should be 32 as they're Full-Time but exceeded their minimum `Contract Hours`
3. ID 3 would return 20.18 as `Top-up Hours` and the Hours returned should be 30
4. ID 4 would return 12.50 as `Top-up Hours` and the Hours returned should be 18

Comment: For your deleted post, you need to separate the lists:  `words = [word for word, count in common_words]; counts = [count for word, count in common_words]; sns.barplot(x=words, y=counts)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are assigning an aggregation back to the original dataframe. They will inherently have different row counts unless there are distinct IDs. I don't fully understand what you're trying to with this line

```
df['Total hours'] = np.where(df['Weekly Hours'] < df['Contract Hours'], df['Contract Hours'], df['Hours'])
```

But I tried out your sample code and the following gave me results similar to what you expect :-

```
total_hours = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'Hours': 'sum', 'Work Status': 'first'})
total_hours['Contract Hours'] = total_hours['Work Status'].map(FTorPT)
total_hours['Top-up Hours'] = total_hours['Contract Hours'] - total_hours['Hours']
```

Result :-

```
   ID   Hours   Work Status Contract Hours Top-up Hours
0   1   9.74    Part-time   18              8.26
1   2   32.00   Full-time   30             -2.00
2   3   9.82    Full-time   30             20.18
3   4   5.50    Part-time   18             12.50
```

This line does the remaining column assignment that you're looking for

```
total_hours['Total hours'] = np.where(total_hours['Hours'] < total_hours['Contract Hours'], total_hours['Contract Hours'], total_hours['Hours'])
```